# C# Writing in the same Data Set in a Multi Threading environment

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've a function that processes several Google Analytics reports. After I receive the data, I turn the JSON into DataTable. 
I'm processing the responses in parallel by doing the following

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
/*Begin of Run Tasks Block*/
tTaskList.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    /*All DataTable Logic here...*/
    //(...)
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Checks if table belongs to ds, if yes merge with the existing table, adds otherwise
        if (ds.Tables.Contains(dt.TableName))
        {
            ds.Tables[dt.TableName].Merge(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
    }
}
Task.WaitAll(tTaskList.ToArray());
//Saves all dts in dataset to file
Business.Common.ExportDataToCsv(ds, Path.Combine(Google.Common.Configuration.FilePath.DownloadsPath));
```

It gives me the following error in my log:

```
[2017-04-21 10:23:40] [Google Analytics] [ERROR] [MoveNext] A DataTable named 'Geographics' already belongs to this DataSet.
```

However this should not happen since I have an `if` clause that verifies if there is a table with that name, if yes it should merge, not add a new one.

This probably needs something that blocks the object when a task is writing on it, however I didn't find an example that fits to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to lock your object when writing.

```
lock(ds)
{
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        //Checks if table belongs to ds, if yes merge with the existing table, adds otherwise
        if (ds.Tables.Contains(dt.TableName))
        {
            ds.Tables[dt.TableName].Merge(dt);
        }
        else
        {
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lock(dt) or lock(ds)?

Comment: Worked for me but only if I lock(ds)